# Scaling in opengl

Tags: opengl, scale

My code works as follows :
A triangle is drawn and then when "1" is clicked the triangle is scaled but what happen is that the triangle is both scaled and translated.

Here is my code:
global variables

```
#include <glut.h>

void Display(void);
void MyKeyboard(unsigned char,int,int);
void MyMouse(int,int,int,int);

int x1 =20 .0f;
int y1 = 30.0f;
int x2 = 40.0f;
int y2 = 50.0f;
int x3 = 60.0f;
int y3 = 10.0f;
```

the main method

```
void main(int argc,char** argr)
{
 glutInit(&argc,argr);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowSize(1000,600);
 glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
 glutCreateWindow("Mouse and Keyboard");
 glutDisplayFunc(Display);
 glutKeyboardFunc(MyKeyboard);
 glutMouseFunc(MyMouse);
 glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
 gluOrtho2D(0.0,1000.0,0.0,600.0);
 glutMainLoop();
}
```

display method

```
void Display()
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
 glPushMatrix();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);

    glVertex3f(x1, 600-y1, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(x2, 600-y2, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(x3, 600-y3, 0.0f);

    glEnd( );
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}
```

keyboard event

```
void MyKeyboard(unsigned char key,int mouseX,int mouseY)
{
    if (key == '1')
    {
        glScaled (0.5f ,0.5f ,1.0f);
        glutPostRedisplay();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

`glScaled()` will essentially cause all your points to be multiplied by the values you supply to `glScaled()`. What this essentially means is that all your vertices will move away from the origin (0,0). To overcome your scaling problem, simply define your triangle to be centered at (0,0).

Obviously you won't always want your triangle to be at zero, so you have to make use of the `glTranslate()` functions.

Ideally you will probably want to change your keyboard function so that it does not call `glScale()` at all, but stores how much should be scaled in some variable. Then, in your render loop, before drawing the triangle, call the translate and scale functions.

Off-topic: Immediate mode OpenGL is deprecated (that is, `glBegin(); glEnd()`). Take a look here for a modern OpenGL tutorial..

http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-1:-The-Graphics-Pipeline.html

Comment: can you give an example with values and numbers please ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to proportionally scale the triangle, then use:

```
glScaled (0.5f ,0.5f ,0.5f);
```

Comment: nothing changed , the triangle is scaled but shifted (translated)

Comment: i need it to remain in its position